# Distributing random marbles among five persons

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

On each round of a game, 20 marbles are distributed at random among five children: A, B, C, D and E.

- A: 4, B: 4, C: 5, D: 4 and E: 3
- A: 4, B: 4, C: 4, D: 4 and E: 4

In many rounds of the game, will there be more results of type I or type II?

Can we say that the probability of both scenarios will be same as $\frac{1}{(4 from 20)}$?

Comment: What exactly counts as a type 1 result?  For example, would 54443 count? In any case, probabilities will NOT be the same

Comment: Why I said equal probability? Because the marbles are not difference and there are 20 same marbles.

Comment: Yes, but the same kid getting all the marbles is not as probable as each getting 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the probability will not be the same, at least not under the scenario that one would usually call 'distributed at random'.

Just like there is a slightly higher probability to see 50 heads out of 100 than to see 49, there is a slightly higher probability of seeing the second configuration (assuming, per asdf's comment, that for the first, we only count exactly the configuration $(4,4,5,4,3)$ and don't also include symmetry-related configurations like $(5,4,4,4,3)$).

The probability of the different configurations here follows a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), but we can just count them up manually. We have five buckets to choose from for each of the twenty objects, so there are $5^{20}$ total possible allocations. For the first configuration, we choose $4$ for bucket A, $4$ of the remaining for bucket B, five of the remaining for bucket C and so on. So that's $$ {20 \choose 4}{16 \choose 4}{12 \choose 5}{7 \choose 4}{3 \choose 3}$$ different allocations that have the configuration $(4,4,5,4,3).$ Dividing this by $5^{20}$ gives approximately $0.00256$ or $0.256\%.$

On the other hand the total number for configuration $(4,4,4,4,4)$ is$$ {20 \choose 4}{16 \choose 4}{12 \choose 4}{8 \choose 4}{4 \choose 4}$$ which, divided by $5^{20}$ gives approximately $0.00320,$ or $0.320\%,$ which is slightly higher, in accord with our intuition from the coin flip example.

Comment: Why I said equal probability? Because the marbles are not difference and there are 20 same marbles.

Comment: @AliJ. But if there were only two kids and 20 marbles, then it's the same thing as coin flips. Would you say the probability of (10,10) was the same as $(11,9)$? If so, you're saying that the probability of getting $10/20$ heads is the same as getting $11/20$ heads. Worse, would you say $(10,10)$ is the same as $(20,0)$? Cause then you'd be saying the probability of getting $10/20$ heads is the same as getting $20/20,$ something that should surely feel intuitively wrong.